# Tool Windows run and logcat android studio 3.5.1 doesn't show action and log

Tags: android-studio

i got some problem when i run-app with xiaomi redmi 2.
i had used different cellphones and it's work, my tool windows run and logcat showed log.

[this is my tool windows run android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pf12v.png)

[this is my tool windows logcat android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2shyK.png)

[this is developer setting in my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhUd0.jpg)

i had restart my adb, re-install my android studio, restart my phone and my laptop. but it doesn't work

Comment: can you check invalidate caches / restart in file menu , can fix the problem ?!

Comment: it can't fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

i think you should open some settings in your phone. Listen,  my HUAWEI phone can set some steps to solve it. Input '*#*#4628579' in the dial app from your phone .find out the 'AP LOG settings' word ,and let  that checkbox  selected.
you can try it.